# sshfs does not seem to work in Colab Enterprise notebook

Tags: fuse, sshfs, google-cloud-colab-enterprise

I've been trying to use `sshfs` to connect a notebook running in Colab Enterprise to my local machine (running an ssh server) and mount a local directory into the remote Runtime. But I get the error `fuse: mount failed: Permission denied` even before the SSH connection is even attempted.

I'm running as root, connecting to the SSH server as another user (i.e. `sshfs someuser@ip` ), and my mount point (in the notebook runtime) exists and is owned by root. What could be happening here ?

Comment: Does this work in free Colab? would you mind sharing the steps to setup sshfs I can try to reproduce it. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh may be a good example?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue you saw. `fuse: mount failed: Permission denied` same issue with GCSfuse: `{"time":"18/11/2023 11:18:06.744235","severity":"INFO","msg":"Start gcsfuse/1.2.1 (Go version go1.21.3) for app \"\" using mount point: /content/gcs-bucket-mount\n"}
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithStorageHandle: Mount: mount: permission denied` I think it has to do with the way we start the Colab container in Colab runtime. Will test further and get back to you.

Comment: I submitted a fix, will keep you posted when this will be available in production. I think of 1-2 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an internal feature request to allow Mount of Fuse systems into Colab Runtime, I submitted the fix and will rollout to production next week. (By Friday 1st should be in all regions)

Answer (score 1):

I tried GCSfuse and worked fine, please try SSHfs which should work as well.

Example:

```
!export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
# This returns gcsfuse-jammy. Replace manually

!echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-jammy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt-get install gcsfuse

# Create a local directory. Here you will mount GCSfuse. (GCS bucket is: $BUCKET_NAME)

!mkdir gcs-bucket-mount
!gcsfuse --implicit-dirs $BUCKET_NAME gcs-bucket-mount
{"time":"07/12/2023 12:05:39.597680","severity":"INFO","msg":"Start gcsfuse/1.2.1 (Go version go1.21.3) for app \"\" using mount point: /content/gcs-bucket-mount\n"}
```